# Database design with multiple types of products

Tags: database, ms-access-2013

I am currently making a new database for a manufacturing company and the problem is as follows:

1) Each design (unique ID) is produced on a specific mould (unique ID) and with specific set of cutting knives.

2) Each design has several operations specified for that design only which need to be done in order to produce the design (product).

[image: At the moment I have the following:]

Basically I have (I believe) completed 1) step, that is, each design having a specific mould and cutting knives assigned in DesignMouldCuttingKnives table.

The entry there would be something like this:

[image: entry]

And so I can query for Design 9017 and make a list of all cutting knives used in the specific design.

I think this would work quite efficiently (I would appreciate suggestions for improvement/rework to this part too if you have any).

My current problem, however, is that each design has specific set of operations required to be done in order to produce it.

For instance, 9017 has 10 unique operations (e.g. 2 of them are cutting some material, 3 of them are stitching the cuts, 2 of them are gluing some stuff together, 2 of them are stitching extra accessories, 1 is packing the stuff up).

Each operation is done by 1 person and so every operation has specific monetary value attached to it (the wage will be calculated using this).

How do I make this as simple as possible, without having to create a unique table for each design itself? The problem is that a specific stitching operation has different monetary value on one design compared to other design and so I cannot simply make a table of all operations and attach the operation ID to specific design as I did with the cutting knives (I think, if it is somehow possible, please let me know).

Any suggestions to make this as simple as possible, assuming it would need to be easily queried for?

I plan to make this in MS Access as the database is aimed to be accessed by 1-5 users locally (not online).

Comment: You say: _'each design has specific set of operations required to be done in order to produce it'._ I cannot see that 'set of operations' table in your database design. If you do not create it explicitly then you will have to 'logically generate' it from your current structure each time you need it.

Comment: I have not made a table with 'set of operations' simply because I am not sure how to approach it in a sensible way. The problem is that the operations are unique for a specific design and so I would think the best way is to expand the DesignList table into multiple tables for each design, that is, table e.g. "9017" and then there will be a list of specific operations. But the problem is that there would be about 2000 of those tables (designs) and that is not really a sensible way.

Comment: Would it help to think of a separate table that holds a list of 'specific operations', each of which has a unique id. Also, a table that holds a list of 'specific designs', each with a unique id. Then a table that relates the 'specific design' to the ''specific operations' with a 'operation order number'?

Comment: I thought of that and I guess it is the only way to do it without having to create a specific table for each Design. Thanks.

Comment: May I also ask: is using MS Access for this a good idea or would you suggest different approach? The database will be accessed locally by 1-5 users with, hopefully, different user access priviledges.

Comment: Could the number of users expand in the future? would it cope with, say, 100 users? I would be tempted to work with a database that handles 'users' naturally. I think there are versions of ms 'sql server' that are cheap and also have the tools to convert from 'ms access'. I would look at those as well as other rdbms' systems. It depends on what you are familiar with more than which of the rdbms's as they all will be fine for what you want to do

Comment: The database is unlikely to be accessed by more than 5 users within any foreseen time period.